# Curiosity about Java sockets and printstream

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I'm learning some Java socket programming and I've managed to make my first ever connection between Server and Client. That sparked a curiosity in me: what would happen if instead of the "Connected" and "Message Received" messages I made a sort of "chat room" type thing, where server and client inputs are printed to one another? So I tried doing just that.

Now, I know this isn't the way chat rooms are created (I'd probably need Threads and whatnot), but I was very curious as to why this didn't work:

Server:

```
public void run() throws Exception
{
    boolean isChatting = true;
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 444);

    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    ps.println("Connected.");

    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader bfrClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String serverMessage = bfr.readLine();
    String clientMessage;

    System.out.println("Server: "+serverMessage);

    while (isChatting)
    {
        clientMessage = bfrClient.readLine();
        ps.println(clientMessage);

        if (clientMessage.toUpperCase().equals("EXIT"))
        {
            isChatting = false;
        }
    }

    bfr.close();
    bfrClient.close();
}
```

Client:

```
public void run() throws Exception
{
    boolean isChatting = true;
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(444); //Port
    Socket sSocket = server.accept();
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(sSocket.getOutputStream());

    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sSocket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader bfrPersonal = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String clientMessage = bfr.readLine();
    String messageToSend;
    System.out.println("Client: "+clientMessage);

    if (clientMessage != null)
    {
        ps.println("Connected.");
    }

    while (isChatting)
    {
        messageToSend = bfrPersonal.readLine();
        ps.println(messageToSend);

        if (messageToSend.toUpperCase().equals("EXIT"))
        {
            isChatting = false;
        }
    }

    bfr.close();
    bfrPersonal.close();
}
```

Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: "this didn't work" ? Well... Do you have an exception ? Which one and where ? Learn to debug before everything else

Comment: Neither side can send a message until after it has displayed a message from the other side. This is a deadlock. You *absolutely* must use threads to make a chat program if you're using blocking sockets.

Comment: @DenysSéguret how do I debug something that literally does nothing? The program just sits there waiting lol...

Comment: @DarthAndroid I see. Thank you :)

Comment: @AlexLeonardi Debugging lets you at least know *where* it stands "doing nothing"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you like to create a chat system the easiest way is to create two threads on the server and two threads on the client side.

- The first thread handle the input of the user and send it.
- The second thread handle the input from the other chat system and print it.

Comment: You don't need two threads on either side to handle this; you only need one.